# How to know if users entered a wrong passcode (lock screen) in android app

Tags: android, lockscreen

I am working on an Android App in which one of the activity has to be completed if user enter a wrong passcode in android lock screen. For example an email sent if user entered a wrong passcode..

I will appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Kshitij

Answer (score 2):

The lock screen are running in a total sandbox environment which makes it makes it inaccessible.You can create a different Application acting as the lock screen and disabling the default android version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by registering your app as **Device Administrator**.
Add `watch-login` tag to device admin metadata and then you will be able to handle `onPasswordFailed` and `onPasswordSucceeded` events.
create a file named `device_admin.xml` in your res/xml folder and put these tags inside it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<device-admin xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-policies>
        <watch-login />
    </uses-policies>
</device-admin>
```

then you need to create a `AdminReciever` class that extends from `DeviceAdminReceiver`. inside this class you can handle `onPasswordFailed` and do what you need if user entered incorrect password.
you can see full example here:
[Password Enforcer Sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/DeviceAdmin/PasswordEnforcer)
**NOTE**
as far as i know, this works only with Password and PIN and Patterns is not supported.